# c# True hide form

Tags: c#, forms, hide

I have 2 forms, `Form1` and `SlimSkin`. Both have buttons to close their form and show the opposite form via:

On `Form1`

```
    private void slimbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var slimform = new SlimSkin();
        slimform.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
```

On `SlimSkin`

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var form1 = new Form1();
        this.Close();
        form1.Show();
    }
```

However, it seems likes when I open or 'show' the form, it creates a new instance of it. For example, I'd open SlimSkin and go back to form1, and if I was to close out of it/stop debugging, there's still an instance of each form running in the background so the program doesn't stop running.

I've also tried

`this.Visible = false;`  and `this.Visible = true;` but it yeilded the same result.

Is there a more effective way of hiding a form and recalling the same hidden form?

Comment: Did you try `this.Hide()` rather than `this.Close()` in `button2_Click`?

Comment: @tnw, yup and same thing. It still continues to run after closing all forms. It's like a new form1 is being created instead of showing the hidden one.

Comment: @EyeSeeSharp put break point and figer out what is heppening when clicking buttons

Comment: How do you plan to effectively close these forms when your users want to end your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your main form creates the child form, hides itself, and shows that form, have it attach a handler to the `FormClosed` event so that it can show itself when that form is closed:

```
private void slimbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var slimform = new SlimSkin();
    slimform.Show();
    slimform.FormClosed += (s, args) => this.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

When the second form closes itself it'll fire the event, which will show the main form, so the second form need only close itself:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you're creating new instance of `Form1` and `SlimSkin` each time in _Click handlers.

Instead you need to add field `MainForm` containing current instance of `Form1` into `SlimSkin` class and similarily field `SlimForm` containing instance of `ClimSkin` into `Form1` class.

Then manipulate your forms something like:

```
public Form SlimForm;
private void slimbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (SlimForm == null)
    {
        SlimForm = new SlimSkin();
        SlimForm.MainForm = this;
    }

    SlimForm.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

And then in `SlimSkin`:

```
private Form MainForm;
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MainForm.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

Here I assuming that `SlimForm` will always be called from `Form1` first. If not - then field `MainForm` should be instantiated before using like in Form1.

Answer (score 0):

On each button click you are creating a new instance of other form. you can try dispose if you want to completely get rid of the instance